# Recommendation needed: IVRS + VoIP solution in Linux

Tags: linux, voip

I know there are some solutions on IVRS and VoIP in some Linux distributions, but I am not sure which one is reliable and stable. Or should I custom build a Linux dedicated for these services?

Please give me some advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asterisk, running on whatever linux distribution you're comfortable with.

Comment: seems a nice solution. Can it use VoIP ?

Comment: Asterisk supports (at least) SIP and SCCP ("Skinny") more-or-less out of the box, so unless you have a very unusual environment, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your best small based voip system is Asterisk. The only issue is that it doesnt have a gui.
If you use freepbx it runs asterisk with a gui and gives you alot more customizing options.